# My ASP.NET website is not responsive on Windows Phone

Tags: asp.net, windows, twitter-bootstrap, smartphone

I have developed a responsive ASP.NET website using Bootstrap.
It resizes perfectly on all smartphones, except on Windows Phone ones.
What's wrong with IE10?

Comment: Can you link to a demo and/or show us the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known bug of IE10.
I imagine you have a real windows phone, because using emulators usually it is not possible to experiment the bug.
The cause is a bad use of viewport width by IE10, you can find this bug documented in [official Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).
If you are using ASP.NET it is really easy to fix it, just add the following code to your master page:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    public void FixWinPhoneIE10Responsiveness(Page page)
    {
        // Build the base style declaration
        var style = new StringBuilder(
            "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
            "@-moz-viewport{width:device-width}" +
            "@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}" +
            "@-o-viewport{width:device-width}" +
            "@viewport{width:device-width}");
        // If the request comes from IE10 on Windows Phone
        //add an additional declaration
        var browserCapabilities = page.Request.Browser;
        if (String.Compare(browserCapabilities.Browser, "IEMobile",
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 &&
            browserCapabilities.MajorVersion == 10 &&
            browserCapabilities.MinorVersionString == "0")
            style.Append("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}");
        style.Append("</style>");
        // Add the style declaration in the page head section
        var placeholder = new Literal {Text = style.ToString()};
        page.Header.Controls.Add(placeholder);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FixWinPhoneIE10Responsiveness(Page);
    }
}
```

If you need more information, I wrote an article on this.
[How to fix your ASP.NET site to be responsive on Windows Phone](http://www.idea-r.it/blog/113/en/how-to-fix-asp-net-web-site-responsive-windows-phone)